# Why does steam forget my birthdate?

Tags: steam

Whenever I visit a store page for an M-rated game, I am prompted with a warning asking my date-of-birth, to prove I'm old enough for the game.  I understand this.  What I don't understand is why it partially forgets my birthdate.  It seems to remember the day and the year correctly, but not the month.  What's going on here?

I am aware of [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/191981/why-does-steam-keep-asking-if-im-over-18) which seems similar at first glance, but is not.  I understand why steam has to ask me my birthdate every time, but I don't understand why it only partially remembers my birthdate.  It gets the day and year correct, but the month always defaults to January.

Comment: @TimmyJim Not really.  I understand why I get the warning, and why I get it every time.  I don't understand why it only remembers the my birth day and year, but not the month.  It gets the day correct and the year correct, but the month is always January, even though I was not born in January.

Comment: "Why does it forget the month" doesn't seem like something we can answer _(nor very useful, since the actual value is mostly irrelevant)_, which only leaves the implied question of _"Why does it keep asking the same question"_, which is a duplicate.